# "Unable to locate element" exception with WebDriver in python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm getting an "Unable to locate element" exception while running the below code. My expected output is "Button not found. This should not happen."
My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(byPassUrl)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='__next']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/button").click()
time.sleep(3)
emails = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='email']")
emails.send_keys("mymail.com")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='password']").send_keys("abcxyz")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Log In"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
def delay(waiting_time=5):
    driver.implicitly_wait(waiting_time)
    
audioBtnFound = False 
 

 
def bypasscaptcha():
    try:
        # switch to recaptcha audio control frame
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        frames = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]").find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
        driver.switch_to.frame(frames[0])
        delay() 
        driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-audio-button").click()

        # get the mp3 audio file
        src = driver.find_element_by_id("audio-source").get_attribute("src")
        print("[INFO] Audio src: %s" % src)

        # download the mp3 audio file from the source
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + "\\sample.mp3"))
        delay()

        # load downloaded mp3 audio file as .wav
        try:
            sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3(os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + "\\sample.mp3"))
            sound.export(os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + "\\sample.wav"), format="wav")
            sample_audio = sr.AudioFile(os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + "\\sample.wav"))
        except Exception:
            print("[ERR] Please run program as administrator or download ffmpeg manually, "
                    "http://blog.gregzaal.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/")

        # translate audio to text with google voice recognition
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sample_audio as source:
            audio = r.record(source)
        key = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("[INFO] Recaptcha Passcode: %s" % key)
        delay()

        # key in results and submit
        driver.find_element_by_id("audio-response").send_keys(key.lower())
        driver.find_element_by_id("audio-response").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

try:
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    frames = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]").find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
    driver.switch_to.frame(frames[0])
    delay() 
    driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-audio-button").click()
    audioBtnFound = driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-audio-button").is_displayed()
except Exception as e:
    print("audioBtn not found")
num = 1
if audioBtnFound:
    try:
        while True:
            print(num)
            num += 1
            bypasscaptcha()
            delay()
            #if eye button found do bypasscaptcha
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-image-button").click()
                print("Fail captcha")
                delay()
                bypasscaptcha()
            except Exception as e: 
                print("Pass captcha")
                audioBtnFound = False
                break
          
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Caught. Need to change proxy now')
else:
    print('Button not found. This should not happen.')
```

If I run the above code I get "Unable to Locate Element Exception".I know that when i log in and no need to bypass captcha this element can not be found "

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]").find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
```

but how can I deal with this problem.
Thank you so much

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

`iframes` tags can be directly found using their `tag name` or `//iframe` xpath. you do not have to look for them after `/html/body/div[3]/div[2]`

**Directly try :**

```
all_iframes = find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
```

and now you have the list of iframe on the page.

if you know the number, then you can switch it like the way you have switched in your code.

Comment: Thanks cruisepandey i will try again

Answer (score 0):

it may be that selenium does not see the tag it needs, or you have registered an incorrect search. Set the search by id or css_selector. Don't do everything in one line, first find

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]")
```

then look for

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
```